# Search all occurences of string in a text file having mutlithreaded output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

My input file contains a multithreaded output from an API and looks like:

```
i-12a: True^M 
i-4e6: False^M  
SSH error 1.1.1.1 i-678 i-9we: True^M
i-890: True^M
SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001 i-007: False^M
SSH error None i-001 i-007: False^M
i-1ae: True^Mi-3644h: True^M
```

The SSH Error will always be present in a new line.
My goal is to get all occurrences of line having `SSH error` but it should be limited to i-* and ignore if the line contains `None`.

e.g. For the above input the output should be like below:

```
SSH error 1.1.1.1 i-678
SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001
```

I am trying to achieve my task using:

```
SSH_ERR="SSH error"
ssh_err=$(awk -v ERROR="$SSH_ERR" '$0~ERROR' <<< $(awk '$0 !~ /None/' < <file>))
```

But it is giving output like below:

```
i-123: True^M i-456: False^M  SSH error 1.1.1.1 i-678 i-987: True^M i-890: True^M SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001 i-007: False^M SSH error None i-001 i-007: False^M
```

Also when you are posting answer. Can you post use bash variable which is `$SSH error` instead of `SSH error`
Help me out.

Comment: I suspect the line you haven't shown us that's "giving output" you've written as `echo $ssh_err` instead of the more correct `echo "$ssh_err"`.

Comment: i am printing using echo "$ssh_err"

Comment: Then your input to the awk command is all on 1 line rather than on separate lines as you show since that awk command will not strip away newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have control M characters in your Input_file so I am adding solution which will remove them too and then print the expected output. So following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /SSH error/{print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file
```

In case you want to have a shell variable's value in `awk` code and then search it then use following:

```
SSH_ERR="SSH error"
awk -v ssh_error="$SSH_ERR" '{gsub(/\r/,"")} $0 ~ ssh_error{print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file
```

OR

```
SSH_ERR="SSH error"
awk -v ssh_error="$SSH_ERR" '{gsub(/\r/,"")} $0 ~ ssh_error && $0 !~ /NONE/{print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file
```

Comment: It works ... if i want to exclude `None` as mentioned in question. Would it be: `awk -v ssh_error="$SSH_ERR"  '{gsub(/\r/,"")} $0 ~ /ssh_error/ && !/None/{print $1,$2,$3}'` Input_file ?
`

Comment: @ojas, yes it should be like that only run it and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: The command i posted earlier is not giving output. It seems that i am making some silly mistake

Comment: `SSH_ERR="SSH error"
awk -v ssh_error="$SSH_ERR" '{gsub(/\r/,"")} $0 ~ ssh_error && $0 !~ /NONE/{print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file` try this once? where `SSH_ERR` is a shell variable.

Comment: @ojas, please check my OR answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/^SSH error/ && !/None/{ print $1,$2,$3,$4 }' file
```

The output:

```
SSH error 1.1.1.1 i-678
SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001
```

Comment: It looks very simple answer. Can give example by using `$SSH error` and not `SSH error`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed

```
sed '/^SSH error/!d;/None/d;s/[^ ]*//5g' infile
```

Comment: It looks very simple answer. Can give example by using `$SSH error ` and not `SSH error`

Comment: @ojas sorry, I don't understand. What do you want to say? Add the requirement in the question.

Comment: edited the question. what i meant was you have used `sed '/^SSH error/!d;/None/d;s/[^ ]*//5g' infile` in your solution. Will this work too: `sed '/^$SSH error/!d;/None/d;s/[^ ]*//5g' infile` too

Comment: SSH_error='SSH error';echo 'SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001 i-007: False^M' | sed '/^'"$SSH_error"'/!d;/None/d;s/[^ ]*//5g'

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/1\.1\.1\../{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

output

```
SSH error 1.1.1.1 i-678
SSH error 1.1.1.2 i-001
```

Comment: but The IP can be anything